# Idiomatic way of specifying default arguments whose presence/non-presence matter

Tags: python, default-arguments

I often see python code that takes default arguments and has special behaviour when they are not specified.

If I for example want behavior like this:

```
def getwrap(dict, key, default = ??):
    if ???: # default is specified
        return dict.get(key, default)
    else:
        return dict[key]
```

If I were to roll my own, I'd end up with something like:

```
class Ham:
    __secret = object()
    def Cheese(self, key, default = __secret):
        if default is self.__secret:
            return self.dict.get(key, default)
        else:
            return self.dict[key]
```

But I don't want to invent something silly when there certainly is a standard. What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Python?

Comment: That is not entirely uncommon, at least in Plone, where it's usually called `_marker`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually prefer

```
def getwrap(my_dict, my_key, default=None):
    if default is None:
        return my_dict[my_key]
    else:
        return my_dict.get(my_key, default)
```

but of course this assumes that None is never a valid default value.

Comment: +1.  If `None` is a valid default value, it's being misused.  It's easy to design things so that `None` really is exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it based on [`*args` and/or `**kwargs`](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Here's an alternate implementation of `getwrap` based on `*args`:

```
def getwrap(my_dict, my_key, *args):
    if args:
        return my_dict.get(my_key, args[0])
    else:
        return my_dict[my_key]
```

And here it is in action:

```
>>> a = {'foo': 1}
>>> getwrap(a, 'foo')
1
>>> getwrap(a, 'bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in getwrap
KeyError: 'bar'
>>> getwrap(a, 'bar', 'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!')
'Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!'
```

Comment: +1 because it is a way to do it. But I can't stand it for readability reasons.